# Regular expression that matches "articles" but not "articles-main"?

Tags: regex, expressionengine

How would I write a regular expression that matches any URL containing the segment `"articles"` followed by any other segment, but does NOT match URLs with the segment `"articles-main"`?

So it would match these:

```
www.mysite.com/articles
www.mysite.com/articles/tinman
```

But not these:

```
www.mysite.com/articles-main
www.mysite.com/articles-main/tinman
```

This is for use in ExpressionEngine if it matters.

Comment: is `article-main` really the only thing you want to avoid in matching, or do you want to avoid anything that has something before or after articles, so e.g. also `www.mysite.com/my_articles` or `www.mysite.com/articles_new` should also not be matched?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a so called **negative lookahead**:

```
articles(?!-main)
```

or more precisely:

```
mysite.com/articles(?!-main)
```

Answer (score 1):

to run counter to @Regexident's advice, i'd recommend a positive lookahead `articles(?=$|\/)`.

This is saying to match `articles` and see if it is followed by a `/` character or the end of the string. That way it won't matter whether you're matching against, `"articles-main"` or `"articlessomethingelse"`.

What this *won't* do is check if articles is its own directory. A value of `http://example.com/some-articles` will match, which might not be acceptable.

If you don't care about whether the `/` characters are included in the match, you could use a regular expression along the lines of:

```
\/articles(?=\/|$)
```

If you do care and you're using PHP's pcre functions, you could use a positive lookbehind (`(?<=)`):

```
(?<=\/)articles(?=\/|$)
```

[More information about these regex assertions can be found on the php.net website.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php)

Answer (score 0):

Look for "articles/". With your examples regex might be a little overkill.

Comment: That would not match `www.mysite.com/articles`

Comment: Just seems like a rather simple case for regex to be used.

Comment: Sure, no doubt about that. It works though. `articles/` not so much. ;)